# First heading of accordian default open withing ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and am trying a ng-repeat within a uib-accordian. And when each heading is clicked, the subsequent project will open and display its users.

But I want the first project to be open by default(that is, for the first project to be passed to expanded(project) by default)

I have tried is-open=$first. Although the first project is open the users are not shown.

```
<uib-accordian close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordian-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <uib-accordian-heading><span ng-click="expanded(project)">{{project.name}}</span></uib-accordian-heading>
            <div ng-repeat="user in project.users">
              //
            </div>
    </div>
</uib-accordian>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **is-open** like this:

```
<uib-accordian close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div is-open="($index==0)" uib-accordian-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <uib-accordian-heading><span ng-click="expanded(project)">{{project.name}}</span></uib-accordian-heading>
            <div ng-repeat="user in project.users">
              //
            </div>
    </div>
</uib-accordian>
```